# Using zip with -T and --password at the same time.

Tags: zip

I'm invoking this command from an application I write.

```
zip -rm9T --password pass123 /home/cats.zip /home/cats-data/
```

I'm setting a password to the archive and I'm specifying that the archive's integrity should be checked after it's creation with the -T switch.

The problem is that the 2 things don't work well with each other.

The archiving part goes well, but when it tries to check the integrity of the archive it doesn't know the password and expects it to come from stdin... I already gave it the password... I don't know why it needs it again... and in such a inconvenient way...

How can I make this work?

Comment: Not a fix (I could not get around the `zip` limitation either) but a workaround: Leave the testing to `unzip` as a second line in your script: `unzip -t -P pass123 /home/cats.zip`.

Comment: This is exactly what I did. Make this into an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: Great minds think alike :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There appears to be no good method to *bypass* this limitation with the `zip` application unfortunately. However if you are scripting this a *good workaround* is to use the `unzip` utility to test the zip file in the subsequent line of your script.

Thus you would have something like the following (omitting the `-T` option for `zip`):

```
zip -rm9 --password pass123 /home/cats.zip /home/cats-data/
unzip -t -P pass123 /home/cats.zip
```

And this should accomplish your goal!

**Notes:**

Options I have used for `unzip` are:

- `-t` test archive files.  This option extracts each specified file in memory  and compares  the  CRC  (cyclic  redundancy  check,  an enhanced checksum) of the expanded file with the original file's stored CRC value.
- `-P` use  password  to  decrypt encrypted zipfile entries (if any).